# Generators for the complexification of $\mathfrak{so}(1, 3)$

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, complex-numbers

As far as I know $\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$ and  $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\Bbb C \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb C \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$

I'm trying to figure out what the generators are, and my understanding is the following:

1. $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$ as a *complex* algebra can be generated by $\left\{ {1\over2}\sigma_i \right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
2. $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$ as a *real* algebra can be generated by $\left\{ {1\over2} \sigma_i, { 1\over2} i\sigma_i \right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
3. $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb C$ as a *complex* algebra can be generated by $\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}{1\over2}\sigma_i\\0\end{matrix}\right) ,\left(\begin{matrix}0\\{1\over2}\sigma_i\end{matrix}\right)\right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
4. $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)_\Bbb C$ as a *real* algebra can be generated by $\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}{1\over2}\sigma_i\\0\end{matrix}\right) ,\left(\begin{matrix}0\\{1\over2}\sigma_i\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix}{1\over2}i\sigma_i\\0\end{matrix}\right) ,\left(\begin{matrix}0\\{1\over2}i\sigma_i\end{matrix}\right)\right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
5. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ as a *real* algebra can be generated by $\left\{ J_i,K_i \right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
6. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\Bbb C$ as a *complex* algebra can be generated by $\left\{ J_i,K_i \right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
7. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\Bbb C$ as a *real* algebra can be generated by $\left\{J_i,K_i, iJ_i, iK_i\right\}_{i=1,2,3}$

where $J_i, K_i$ are the usual generators of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$.

8. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\Bbb C$ as a *complex* algebra can be also generated by $\left\{ J_i^+,J_i^-\right\}_{i=1,2,3}$
9. $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)_\Bbb C$ as a *real* algebra can be also generated by $\left\{ J_i^+,J_i^-, iJ_i^+,iJ_i^- \right\}_{i=1,2,3}$

where $J_i^{\pm}={1\over 2}(J_i \pm iK_i)$

Is that correct or I am misunderstanding something?